# Intel(R) Visual Fortran run-time error on elevated permissions for DISM

Tags: command-line, fortran, command-prompt, elevated-privileges, dism

I have written a simple Fortran code as follows:

```
!call system ('dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart')
call execute_command_line ('dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:VirtualMachinePlatform /all /norestart')
end
```

When I run it using Intel(R) Visual Fortran compiler with Visual Studio, I am getting following error message:

```
Error: 740

Elevated permissions are required to run DISM.
Use an elevated command prompt to complete these tasks.
```

Any suggestion please to overcome this.

Thank you very much in advance for your time and help in this matter,

Bakbergen

Comment: You need to run that command with elevated privileges - as admin. I do not think you can elevate privileges for a command called from Intel Fortran. You will have to run your program as admin.

Comment: If you google you error message, my first suggestion whenever you have any problem, you get quite a few relevant hits, most of which agree with Vladimir's suggestion - see for example https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/command-prompt-error-740/72ee2cf0-7818-49a0-9f80-0cd1020b9fd2

Answer (score 0):

I have this trouble when run PowerShell with user roots. Try to run PowrShell as Administer.
In my case it was helped me